UBUNTU 22.04 MIDI & audio issues
I have both Polyphone & Drumstick virtual Piano
and an Axiom25 Midi controller, issue is that the programs will output audio in response to the computer IO, that is mouse & Keyboard.  When attempting to use the Midi controller, the display indicates that a key has been pressed, but there isn't any sound.  VERY perplexing - what would anyone suggest?
& Thanks
Bob
